# NPOI скопировать строку и вставить в другой лист

Tags: c#, excel, xls, apache-poi, xlsx

Вот моя функция, но она не копирует объединенные ячейки, не могу найти в чем проблема:

```
public void CopyAndInsertRowSheet(XSSFWorkbook workBook, ISheet sheet, ISheet sheet2, int sourceRowNum, int destinationRowNum)
    {
        IRow newRow = sheet2.GetRow(destinationRowNum);

        if (sheet.GetRow(sourceRowNum) == null)
        {
            sheet.CreateRow(sourceRowNum);
        }

        IRow sourceRow = sheet.GetRow(sourceRowNum);

        if (newRow != null)
        {
            sheet2.ShiftRows(destinationRowNum, sheet2.LastRowNum, 1);
        }
        else
        {
            newRow = sheet2.CreateRow(destinationRowNum);
        }

        // Loop through source columns to add to new row
        for (int i = 0; i < sourceRow.LastCellNum; i++)
        {
            // Grab a copy of the old/new cell
            ICell oldCell = sourceRow.GetCell(i);
            ICell newCell = newRow.CreateCell(i);

            // If the old cell is null jump to next cell
            if (oldCell == null)
            {
                newCell = null;
                continue;
            }

            // Copy style from old cell and apply to new cell
            ICellStyle newCellStyle = workBook.CreateCellStyle();
            newCellStyle.CloneStyleFrom(oldCell.CellStyle);
            newCell.CellStyle = newCellStyle;

            // If there is a cell comment, copy
            if (oldCell.CellComment != null)
            {
                newCell.CellComment = oldCell.CellComment;
            }

            // If there is a cell hyperlink, copy
            if (oldCell.Hyperlink != null)
            {
                newCell.Hyperlink = oldCell.Hyperlink;
            }

            // Set the cell data type
            newCell.SetCellType(oldCell.CellType);

            // Set the cell data value
            switch (oldCell.CellType)
            {
                case CellType.Blank:
                    newCell.SetCellValue(oldCell.StringCellValue);
                    break;
                case CellType.Boolean:
                    newCell.SetCellValue(oldCell.BooleanCellValue);
                    break;
                case CellType.Error:
                    newCell.SetCellErrorValue(oldCell.ErrorCellValue);
                    break;
                case CellType.Formula:
                    newCell.SetCellFormula(oldCell.CellFormula);
                    break;
                case CellType.Numeric:
                    newCell.SetCellValue(oldCell.NumericCellValue);
                    break;
                case CellType.String:
                    newCell.SetCellValue(oldCell.RichStringCellValue);
                    break;
            }
        }

        // If there are are any merged regions in the source row, copy to new row
        for (int i = 0; i < sheet.NumMergedRegions; i++)
        {
            CellRangeAddress cellRangeAddress = sheet.GetMergedRegion(i);
            if (cellRangeAddress != null)
            {
                if (cellRangeAddress.FirstRow == sourceRow.RowNum)
                {
                    CellRangeAddress newCellRangeAddress = new CellRangeAddress(newRow.RowNum,
                              (newRow.RowNum +
                                         (cellRangeAddress.LastRow - cellRangeAddress.FirstRow
                                                    )),
                              cellRangeAddress.FirstColumn,
                              cellRangeAddress.LastColumn);
                    sheet.AddMergedRegion(newCellRangeAddress);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста, что именно не копирует. Например, CellValue эта функция копирует. Идеально, если сможете уточнить в виде теста.

Comment: @Uranus объединенные ячейки не копирует

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы копируете в оригинальный лист

```
sheet.AddMergedRegion(newCellRangeAddress);
```

А хотите копировать во второй

```
sheet2.AddMergedRegion(newCellRangeAddress);
```

Назовите эти переменные `sourceSheet` и `destinationSheet` чтобы избежать путаницы.